# sending JSON to google app engine datastore

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So I've been scouring the interwebs and I cant find anything that works for me.  I have a simple html form that I need to send via JSON to the app engine datastore.

HTML form:

```
<form method="get" name="vehicle-form" id="vehicle-form">
            <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Vehicle Type" requried>
            <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Make" requried>
            <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model" requried>
            <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year" requried>
            <button id="submit-btn">Add</button>
</form>
```

Javascript: **EDIT:** Changed this- now all the values are going in as null

```
var formData = {};
            $("#part-form").serializeArray().map(function (x) { formData[x.name] = x.value; });

            //var par = document.getElementById("test2");
            //par.innerHTML += "<p>";
            //for (var i in formData) {
            //    par.innerHTML += formData[i] + "<br>";
            //}
            //par.innerHTML += "</p>";
            var uriString = myUrl;
            $.ajax({
                url: uriString,
                type: "POST",
                //data: JSON.stringify(formData)
                data: { "type" : formData[0], "quantity" : formData[1], "cost" : formData[2], "vehicle_id" : formData[3] }
            });
```

I am doing this on a windows 8 phone, and the success function doesn't execute, and no data is added to the datastore.

Here is the backend code for the POST request

```
class AddVehicle(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    """Creates a vehicle entity

    POST Vehicle Variables:
    vehicle_type = vehicle type - required
    make = Make - requried
    model = Model - required
    year = Year - required
    """
    new_vehicle = Vehicle()
    vehicle_type = self.request.get('type', default_value=None)
    make = self.request.get('make', default_value=None)
    model = self.request.get('model', default_value=None)
    year = self.request.get('year', default_value=None)

    # all required info
    new_vehicle.vehicle_type = vehicle_type
    new_vehicle.make = make 
    new_vehicle.model = model 
    new_vehicle.year = year 

    self.response.write(new_vehicle)

    # post data into datastore
    key = new_vehicle.put()
    out = new_vehicle.to_dict()
    self.response.write(json.dumps(out))
    return
```

This is the ndb model

```
class Vehicle(ndb.Model):
vehicle_type = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
make = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
model = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
year = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Comment: what do you mean? do you have anything on backend side?

Comment: Yes I'm using a web api via the google app engine on the backend.  I can't get it to POST the data to the datastore

Comment: can you show your backend code then? does it receive request?

Comment: First thing do some basic debuggubg, check the server logs to see if you code is even calling your server with the POST.  If it, is there an error in the logs ? If yes, then there is your problem. If no, then start by placing logging statements in your backend code to see what is going on.

Comment: Checked the server logs, and it is getting the request.  I'm getting a BadValueError(Entity has uninitialized properties: make, vehicle_type, model, year).  Google says its not getting the required Vehicle params. Changing the required to False.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
$.ajax({
                url: uriString,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", //<-- THIS
                data: { type: vehicle_type, make: vehicle_make, model: vehicle_model, year: vehicle_year },
                success: function (result) {
                    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/vehicleAdd/vehicleAdd.html");
                }
            });
```

Turns out I needed to send url encoded form data instead of json...